# GraphCmd.exe : URI formats are not supported

Tags: validation, architecture, visual-studio-2012, model, msbuild

I am trying to validate architecture through MsBuild in my CI server. I have a design model project(.modelproj) in my solution and I have changed the project file to load the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.ModelingProject.targets` from a separate location other than the default location.

Everything works fine except this awkward error. Even though I dumped the .dgql file and see it's content, I couldn't figure out the issue with it.

```
dgql file - '*/"Microsoft.FileSystem.ProcessFile"("C:\build-dir\AMXB-AMBTMP-JOB1\Source\DesignModel\LayerDiagram.layerdiagram")/ + FilePath.Equals("C:\build-dir\AMXB-AMBTMP-JOB1\Source\DesignModel\LayerDiagram.layerdiagram")/"LayerDesigner.LoadArchitecture"/ */"Microsoft.AllNodes"
```

What might be the issue with this project? Any help is highly appreciated.